# Facebook FQL - what is difference between normalized_url and url in link_stat table

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

`url` is the indexed field in table `link_stat` for querying number of likes, etc. for a given url, but the table also contains a field `normalized_url`.  No explanation in the sparse Facebook documentation, other than "The normalized URL for the page being shared."

Once I've queried a record, should I refer to `url` or `normalized_url`, and what is the difference?